# Can user's custome code at MobileFirst security check revoke the OAuth token?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

My customer is thinking to make to new internet banking mobile application(B2C).

The scenario is that a bank customer has two devices.
When he had used one device to login the app and lost the device, he was going to use another device and login the app,
The customer would like to invalidate the OAuth token of the app. in first device.
This scenario needs that user's custome code at MobileFirst security check revoke the OAuth token.

Is that possible for MobileFirst Foundation V8.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following blog post which enables you to limit the number of devices a user can login with. For example, only 1 device at at time: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/07/limit-the-number-of-devices-per-authenticated-user/